# Add active class to jquery dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add an active class to the parent list item on a jquery dropdown when the child unordered list appears.
Basically on hover of the child items I want an active class on the parent li.

Code below:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="Menu" class="Nav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="Dropdown"><a href="#">About Us</a> // WANT TO ADD CLASS HERE
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Perspex Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What We Believe</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Values</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Product Qualities</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Nav li').hover(
    function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
    },
    function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
    }
    );
    $('.Nav li:has(> ul)').addClass('HasChild');
});
```

**CSS**

```
    ul.Nav
   {
       margin:9px 0 0 0;
       padding:0;
       float:right;
   }

   ul.Nav li
   {
       display:inline-block;
       margin-right:-4px;
       list-style:none;
   }

   ul.Nav li a
   {
       text-decoration:none;
       text-transform:uppercase;
       color:#666666;
       font-size:12px;
       padding:8px 18px;
       display:block;
   }

   ul.Nav li.Selected a
   {
       color:#1ead34;
   }

   ul.Nav li a:hover
   {
       background-color:#1EAD34;
       color:#ffffff;
   }

   ul.Nav li.HasChild a:hover:after
   {
       color:#ffffff !important;
   }

   ul.Nav li:last-child a
   {
       padding-right:0;
   }

   ul.Nav li ul
   {
       display:none;
       position:absolute;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       z-index:100;
       background-color:#EBEBEB;
   }

   ul.Nav li ul li
   {
       display:block;
   }

   ul.Nav li ul li a
   {
       padding:8px 18px;
       display:block;
   }

   ul.Nav li.HasChild a:after
   {
       color: #666666;
       content: "v";
       font-size: 7px;
       left: 6px;
       position: relative;
       top: -2px;
   }

   ul.Nav li.HasChild a:hover:after, ul.Nav li.HasChild a.Selected:after
   {
       color:#1ead34;
   }

   ul.Nav li.HasChild ul li a:after
   {
       content:"";
   }
```

Thanks:) Link to JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JR9Rk/

Comment: And what is Your problem? :)

Comment: Yes, you are trying to add an active class to the parent list item on a jquery dropdown when the child unordered list appears, and What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry maybe  I worded this wrong. Basically on hover of the child items I want an active class on the parent li

Comment: Note: "when the child unordered list appears."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add a class. Just try this

```
$('.Dropdown ul').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color','#1EAD34');
    $(this).parent().css('color','#ffffff');
    //$(this).parent().addClass('HasChild'); Even if you want to add class add this line
},
function(){
    $(this).parent().css('background-color','white');
    //$(this).parent().removeClass('HasChild');// if you added class  remove it 
});
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JR9Rk/4/)

If you want to add more list items, then make use of `Id` or `class`. Here is an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JR9Rk/7/)

Comment: Thanks, but if I add another list item both of them get selected? http://jsfiddle.net/JR9Rk/5/

Comment: If so then change the class or give Id

Answer (score 1):

You successfully added the class via jquery but that class is not available in your CSS. Add this first.

```
.HasChild{
   background-color:#1EAD34;
   color:#ffffff;
}
```

then change your js like [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JR9Rk/2/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Nav > li').hover( function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideDown(300);
    },  function () {
        $('ul', this).stop().slideUp(300);
    });

    $('li.Dropdown ul li').on('mouseover',function(){
       $(this).parent().prev().addClass('HasChild');
    }).on('mouseout',function(){
       $(this).parent().prev().removeClass('HasChild');    
    });
});
```